# Elasticsearch 6.3 query with space in a keyword field and not returning all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the fallowing part of a mapping:

```
"name": {
    "store": "true",
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

and this query:

```
{
    "query":{
        "query_string":{
            "query":"+(name:John Doe)",
            "fields":[

            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations":{

        "name":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"name",
                "size":10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query should return over 100 results however it only returns a few. If I add quotes to John Doe like this: \"John Doe\" then it returns all the desired results.

I'm wondering why this happens. Isn't enough that the field is mapped as keyword so that John Doe is analyzed as a whole, and no quotes should be added? Also, why would it return less items without quotes?

Note: In ES 1.4 the same query seems to work fine (although is not the same data to be honest, and it uses facets instead of aggregations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) for `query string` query clearly states:

> If the field is a `keyword` field the analyzer will create a **single** term ...

So you don't need to add quotes to your search string. Instead, you need to write your query correctly. Currently your query try to find the term `John` in field `name`, and term `Doe` in [all other fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_default_field)! So you must rewrite your query in one of the following ways:

1. Add parentheses to your search term so the query parser can "understand" that all words must be found in `name` field:

   ```
   {
       "query": {
           "query_string": {
               "query": "+(name:(John Doe))",
               "fields": [

               ]
           }
       },
       "aggregations": {
           "name": {
               "terms": {
                   "field": "name",
                   "size": 10
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Specify field name in `fields` array rather than in query string:

   ```
   {
       "query": {
           "query_string": {
               "query": "+(John Doe)",
               "fields": [
                   "name"
               ]
           }
       },
       "aggregations": {
           "name": {
               "terms": {
                   "field": "name",
                   "size": 10
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```